# How to put a sample of my data in dendrogram generated with hclust package in R

Tags: r, label, sample, hclust

I want to put in the labels of my dendrogram the samples name that I have in column 1 associated with the environments that I have in column 2, but I cannot find the solution.

I am using this code of hclust package:

```
d <- dist(mydata, method = "euclidean") # distance matrix
fit <- hclust(d, method="ward.D")
par(cex=0.3, mar=c(5, 8, 4, 1))
plot(fit)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a sample of your data.  Use the output of `dput(head(mydata, 20))`

Comment: Thank you @Dave2e for the reply. I don't know why, but using the output of 
dput(head(mydata, 20)) my R sessions gets aborted. Do you know another way to do it?

Comment: Can you make up some data or use a built-in dataset (e.x. 'mtcars') to demonstrate?